# MySQL trigger doesn't response, WHY?

Tags: trigger

I am new to SQL and I don't know where to get help.
I faced a problem while using the trigger, but it doesn't response.
This is my code here:

```
DELIMITER $$                                                

CREATE TRIGGER payments_after_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON payments        
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    UPDATE invoices 
    SET payment_total = payment_total + NEW.amount
    WHERE invoice_id = NEW.invoice_id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the second part:

```
INSERT INTO payments                                        
VALUES (DEFAULT, 5, 3, '2019-01-01', 10, 1)
```

I execute the first part, then the second.
Strangely the new data has been inserted, but the triggers don't.

Can someone help me?
I have been searching for the answers for few days and I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Provide complete scripts pack (CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO with some sample data) which allows to reproduce your task completely.

Answer (score 0):

A model:

```
-- sample structures and data
CREATE TABLE payments (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  column1 INT,
  column2 INT,
  somedate DATE,
  amount INT,
  invoice_id INT
);
INSERT INTO payments VALUES 
  (DEFAULT, 5, 3, '2018-01-01', 15, 1),
  (DEFAULT, 5, 3, '2018-02-02', 55, 2);
CREATE TABLE invoices (
  invoice_id INT,
  payment_total INT
);
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES (1,15), (2,55);
SELECT * FROM invoices;
SELECT * FROM payments;
```

| invoice_id | payment_total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 55 |

| id | column1 | column2 | somedate | amount | invoice_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | 2018-01-01 | 15 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2018-02-02 | 55 | 2 |

```
-- trigger (copied from the question)
CREATE TRIGGER payments_after_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON payments        
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    UPDATE invoices 
    SET payment_total = payment_total + NEW.amount
    WHERE invoice_id = NEW.invoice_id;
END
```

```
-- insertion (copied from the question)
INSERT INTO payments                                        
VALUES (DEFAULT, 5, 3, '2019-01-01', 10, 1)
```

```
-- looking for final data state
SELECT * FROM invoices;
SELECT * FROM payments;
```

| invoice_id | payment_total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 55 |

| id | column1 | column2 | somedate | amount | invoice_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | 2018-01-01 | 15 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | 2018-02-02 | 55 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 2019-01-01 | 10 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OXcOPSGK)